# How to ignore values for a counter if it starts increasing at a very high rate

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am reading values from a hall sensor. Whenever the hall sensor is in the vicinity of a magnet, it gives a low signal. The issue on a rotating wheel is that when the magnet is stuck in a position facing the hall sensor, it keeps on getting getting continuous zeros. I am using it to count the number of rotations. In order to avoid that in the code, I would like to take the last value of the counter before it got stuck on the magnet and ignore all other values after that until I either stop reading values from the sensor or until the wheel moves such that the sensor is away from the magnet. During the period the magnet is stuck facing the sensor, it gets around 20 Active low signal(0) in 5 seconds.

How can I implement that in my code ?

The current code that I am using now is,

```
while (flag = True):
     sensor = GPIO.input(16)
     if (sensor==0):
          counter = counter +1
```

EDIT: I need to actually read the values continuously. It is supposed to get a zero once in 5 seconds or so based on speed of rotation. Only when it is stuck facing the sensor it gets constant zeros (like 10 zeros in 3 seconds), which I should be able to ignore using the code. That is, basically I should be able to ignore the values when the rate at which it is getting zeros is very high, and the counter value should be set to the value which it had just before the counter starts increasing at that rapid arte. Once the rate at which the sensor gets zeros decreases, counter should start counting

Comment: Your first line is wrong; it should be `while (flag == True):` or simply `while flag == True:`.

Comment: Ha I'm asleep today, that's even better.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't particularly difficult, but the amount of code you've shown makes it hard to know exactly what you want.  You say you're recording this counter somehow, but only show it being incremented.  Is this a function or method of some sort that returns this counter?  Is it written at the time to a database?  Maybe you could add a little more code, or explain further.

Comment: @Gerrat  what I meant was, the counter value gets incremented by 1 each time, it gets a zero value from the sensor. So, during normal rotations counter value would increase by 1 every 3 or more seconds. But during rotation, if the magnet gets stuck in front of the sensor, sensor will get continuous zeros and counter value will increase rapidly.so,when this rapid increase of zeros happens, I want the counter to stop incrementing and hold on to its value which it had before this rapid increase of 0's.once rate at which the sensor is getting values decreases, counter shd start incrementing again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your sensor reads values faster than the wheel spins, (so that you'll never get two valid 0's in a row), just track the last value to make sure you don't get two zeros in a row:

```
last_sensor = None  # or object()
while flag:
    sensor = GPIO.input(16)
    if (sensor==0 and sensor != last_sensor):
        counter = counter +1
    last_sensor = sensor
```

---

**EDIT:**
You want to ignore the sensor if the rate it is getting values at is very high, but use the values if it is getting them at a `normal` rate.

When you say `"10 zeros in 3 seconds"`, you likely don't really mean that (9 readings 1 microsecond apart, but with the preceding and following reading being 4 seconds off would mean that all readings would be valid).  ...so it sounds like what you really want would be if one reading of zero was too close to the previous reading (using your numbers, by 3/10 seconds), then ignore it.  If this is all you want, you'd just use the above code, but with a time constraint instead:

```
import time
last_time = time.time() - 10  # ensure we get the first reading
min_gap = 3/10.0  # minimum number of seconds between zeros

while flag:
    sensor = GPIO.input(16)
    cur_time = time.time()
    if sensor==0:
        if cur_time - last_time > min_gap:
            counter = counter +1
        last_time = cur_time
```

Comment: @bobdxcool:  Sorry, I don't follow what you're asking/saying.

Comment: But I need to actually read the values continuously. It is supposed to get a zero once in 5 seconds or so based on speed of rotation. Only when it is stuck facing the sensor it gets constant zeros (like 10 zeros in 3 seconds), which I should be able to ignore using the code. That is, basically I should be able to ignore the values when the rate at which it is getting zeros is very high, and the counter value should be set to the value which it had just before the counter starts increasing at that rapid arte. Once the rate at which the sensor gets zeros decreases, counter should start counting

Comment: I'm still not following you.  Doesn't the `while flag:`, and `sensor = GPIO.input(16)` read values continuously?  If it does, then the counter will only increment when the sensor is 0 and the last sensor reading was not zero.  Once it gets one zero, it should ignore any more until it gets a non-zero value first.

Comment: I would think what I've posted should work, but if I understand correctly you'd rather do something more complicated based on timing?

Comment: Yes it is based on timing. The sensor should get 1 pulse for every 3 seconds or so. But, if it is getting more than 8 values or so in 3 seconds, that means the counter should ignore this increase, and should hold on to its last value it had just before the rate of getting zeros increased. After the rate goes back to normal (1 zero for every 3 seconds or so), then it should start incrementing again from its previous value.

Comment: what is happening is that in your code, the code is ignoring counter values for the min_gap, but after the gap it starts counting again. But, my problem is that magnet might be stuck near sensor for a really long time (like more than min_gap), and I want to ignore counter values for the whole time it is being stuck and giving constant zeros.